# How to make a loading screen in Unity, that can figure out if the scene is fully loaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my main menu; when the game start, it takes between 2 and 12 seconds to display the scene. During this time everything is still, and the user may think that the application is hanging or crashed.

I would like to add a simple screen (I can use a canvas and place a simple animation on it with the loading text on it), but I can't get how do you actually tell that the scene loaded.

I did try the delegate "OnLevelWasLoaded", and it is a big lie, because the code running in there is not necessarly happening when everything "pop" on screen and you can start to use the application.

I did try to add a timed function, but it is totally bogus, since I have no way to find out if the scene loaded or not, so on some machines it may be faster, and the game would run behind the loading canvas; while if I do it too short then the scene will not be fully loaded and I would end up showing again the frozen screen.

Beside OnLevelWasLoaded, is there anything else that can be used to intercept when the scene loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

`LoadSceneAsync` returns `AsyncOperation`that you can use in coroutine.

Here you can find more details: [Doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

So you can add a loading scene that will start to load proper level asynchronously, this allow you to check when loading is completed.

Comment: I didn't realize that the async is now in Unity free too. I will give it a try, thanks for the reply.